# Ant Design - Select - remove/hide dropdown when there is no data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have tried notFoundContent={undefined} but it does not work.
Is there any way else to solve this???

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us some code that you have written or any minimal example?

Comment: @Hypermystic Hi bro! I've just updated image and I want to hide/remove that red rectangle. Can you help me???

Comment: @Nomad you may wanna use the `open` prop like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/ji-ben-shi-yong-antd-4-21-7-forked-gnp4cy?file=/demo.js) example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to hide dropdown when there is no data, you can use:

```
notFoundContent={null}
```

instead of:

```
notFoundContent={undefined}
```